# How can I fix : [Error] expected ')' before '+' token?

Tags: c, pointers

Below is the piece of code I am getting an error as:  "[Error] expected ')' before '+' token". This is a C code and I am using Devc++ compiler. I am trying to get the pointer to the a0, to point to the a0+IMAGNARY_INDEX by using *(a0+IMAGNARY_INDEX) instead of *a0 . Is this a wrong way to use it? If so how can I fix this mistake?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <x86intrin.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #define IMAGINARY_INDEX  510
    
    void F(int16_t a[], int16_t b[], int16_t c[], int n){
    
        int n3 = n/3;
        //int p_size = 2*n3-1;
        int p_size = (n3 << 1) - 1;
    
        int16_t *a0 = a;
        int16_t *(a0+IMAGINARY_INDEX)= a+IMAGINARY_INDEX;
```

Comment: For an assignment, get rid of `int16_t` in the last line. The way it is, the line starts as another declaration and `*(a0+IMAGINARY_INDEX)` is no variable name.

Comment: `a+IMAGINARY_INDEX` will not work anyway

Comment: Besides removing `int16_t` you should also take a look at what you actually is trying to do with that line. LHS is an `uint16_t` and RHS is a `uint16_t` pointer.... Assigning a pointer to a `uint16_t` is not good

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to declare a variable (by naming a type first, `int16_t`) when you're actually just making an assignment. Parentheses are allowed in declarations (`int (a);` is equivalent to `int a;`, and parenthesizing is necessary for more complex declarators like function pointers), but arbitrary expressions (and thus, the `+` operator) are not, and that's why you're getting the error.

Underneath all of this lies the error of mistreating that line as a declaration. `*(a0 + IMAGINARY_INDEX)` is a dereferenced pointer — something that already exists, like a declared variable. Therefore, the "fix" is to simply assign to it: `*(a0 + IMAGINARY_INDEX) = a + IMAGINARY_INDEX;`. Note that this will trigger a separate warning: since the right-hand side is a pointer and the left-hand side is an integer, this is an implicit pointer-to-integer conversion, which will warn on virtually any compiler you can find (even though technically allowed by the C standard). That warning signals a mistake almost every time, and you should never ignore it.

Ultimately, that line is entirely ill-formed. By declaring `int16_t * a0 = a;`, both `a0` and `a` point to the same place, and therefore so will `a0 + IMAGINARY_INDEX` and `a + IMAGINARY_INDEX`. You don't need to do anything at all for that to work — that line is entirely unnecessary, because `a0` and `a` have the same value (and thus adding the same thing to both will result in the same result). It's equivalent to trying to do `b + 3 = a + 3;` after you've done `b = a;` — invalid *and* unnecessary.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232923/discussion-on-answer-by-aaaaaa123456789-how-can-i-fix-error-expected-bef).